# Jetty serve static file without specifying file extension

Tags: apache, jetty, http-status-code-404, static-content

I have a jetty server and have a file abc.jpg present in a folder in my webapps directory.

When I hit the following URL,

> www.xyz_server.com/abc/def.jpg

I can see my image.

But, when I hit

> www.xyz_server.com/abc/def

I get a 404 error

The same procedure works if I am serving the  static content through apache. How do I configure jetty to display images (static content) without extensions, like apache does?

Comment: Strange, my copy of Apache Httpd (2.4.10 on Fedora 20) doesn't support this.  Maybe you have a rewrite or redirect rule that does it for you.

Comment: Could be `mod_mime` or `mod_mime_magic` doing that for you on Apache Httpd.  If so, then the features of `mod_mime_magic` are not supported on Jetty.